# Entendimento da sysprocesses

Tags: sql

Estou utilizando a tabela `sys.sysprocesses` no `SQL 2012/2014`, para identificar através do campo `CONTEXT_INFO`, qual usuário de uma determinada aplicação está atrelado a uma determinada sessão.

Criei uma função passando como parâmetro o `SPID`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FC_RETORNAUSUARIO] (@spid INTEGER)  
RETURNS sysname  
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER  
AS  
BEGIN  

DECLARE @username sysname;

SET @username = suser_sname() DECLARE @contextinfo varbinary(128)
SELECT @contextinfo = context_info
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @spid DECLARE @offset int DECLARE @usernamelength int
  SET @usernamelength = substring(@contextinfo, datalength(@contextinfo), 1)
  SET @offset = datalength(@contextinfo) - @usernamelength - sign(@usernamelength) IF @usernamelength <> 0x00
  SET @username = convert(sysname, substring(@contextinfo, @offset, @usernamelength))
  SET @offset = @offset - 1 RETURN @username;

END;
```

A partir disso, fiz um teste com a aplicação instalada localmente e junto a instância utilizada para se conectar e deu certo. Consegui com que ele passasse o usuário da aplicação.

Porém ao colocar em um servidor, percebi que as informações do `CONTEXT_INFO` vinham vazias. E que o usuário do banco em que a aplicação se conectava não possuía integração com o Windows, ou seja, foi um usuário criado apenas para acesso ao banco.

O fato do usuário não ter integração com o Windows (não seja do domínio do servidor) é o que faz com que o `context_info` não seja preenchido?